# Improve page rendering time having gridview, child gridview and grand child gridview on it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page where there is a grand parent grid - displaying categories. Then under each category comes Items - the second grid and under each item come one or more sub-items again a grid. The number of categories, items, sub-items vary based on the shop selected from previous page in the flow. My question is how can i improve rendering of the page? It is taking too much of time to render above data.

Note:- i cannot use paging in the grid....

I bind the items grid on RowDataBound event of categories grid and Sub-Items on RowDataBound event of Items grid.

Comment: Use cache to save the rendered grid on.

Comment: @Aristos: caching will not help as every time the list may change based on the shop selected by user on previous page. What i am interested in is how to render the list quickly for first time.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating way too many grids. A grid is an expensive component.

You could alter your user interface to allow users to select an Item and bind the inner grid only on selection. This ensures that rather than one grid per row or parent grid, you will have only one child grid displayed at a time.

Comment: what you mentioned is the solution that i gave to the client, but he is interested in displaying list at once to his customers. he does not want to show items on some click event or so...

Comment: Ah! A painful client.Another workaround is to join your data in a stored procedure, and display that in one grid. Thats a lot lesser controls, though it shows the same data.

Comment: I appreciate what you suggested as i thought about this solution, but the question is how to fetch all this data in just single table from DB, maintianing structure of data. Say for example i have following structure of data:

Category1       Item1        Sub-Item1
                             Sub-Item2
                             Sub-Item3
Category2       Item2        Sub-Item4
                             Sub-Item5
Category3       Item3        Sub-Item6

Is there a work around to this?

Comment: You can definitely achieve this using joins. Ofcourse, columns from the parent like category would repeat in each row.

Comment: that is what pinches me, Parent should aprear one for all its children and then child should appear just once for all grand children...

Comment: If you do want to process a lot of data and can't even change the rendering, then usually the only option is to throw hardware at it(a stronger machine). I can't comment more without seeing all your code, but reducing the database queries in such cases will improve performance a lot.